# how to connect via REST at IBM DB2?

Tags: rest, db2

i create a DB2 service in IBM cloud and i read that i can access at my db via REST.

so, i try to connect using this:

```
curl -k -X POST 'https://MY_DB_URL/dbapi/v4/auth/tokens' 
   -d '{"userid":"MY_SERVICE_USER", "password":"MY_SERVICE_PASSWORD"}'
```

and the response is always:

```
{"trace":"TRACE_CODE","errors":
   [{
     "code":"invalid_parameters",
     "message":"HWCSEC0012E: The credential is invalid! For regular credentials, both the user name and password are required. For IAM API key or token credentials, they mustn't be empty.",
     "target":{"type":"","name":""},
     "more_info":""
   }]
}
```

i really don't know how to solve that.

docs:

1. https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/db2-on-cloud#request-a-new-access-token
2. https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/85/api/db2whc/

Comment: Are you using the Db2 credentials?

Comment: hi data_henrik, under my DB2 service I creat a "credential of service" and i use username and password of it. (i don't use my cloud ibm account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solve. they want in header
    {Content-Type: text/plain}
it's not make sense, the body is a json...